# Grouping & Sorting in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of customer and i need to sort and group the list according to business rule.

- Group by Customer Name
- Sort by Customer Name in alphabetical order
- if there are several results for the same name, then they need to sorted by date of birth in ascending order (the oldest is listed first)

Below is the entity.

```
public class Customer
{
 public string FirstName {get; set;}
 public string LastName {get; set;}
 public DateTime DateofBirth {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

```
customers.GroupBy(c => c.FirstName)
.Select(c => c.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName).ThenBy(c => c.LastName));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your business rules are somewhat conflicting:
`Group by Customer Name` implies that you won't have multiple occurrences of the same name in the resulting list. Yet your third rule is `if there are several results for the same name, then they need to sorted by date of birth`. So if by grouping in rule #1 you mean sorting, your query would be merely:

```
customers.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName).
          ThenBy(c => c.LastName).
          ThenBy(c => c.DateofBirth);
```

In case you actually mean grouping, rule #3 becomes the criteria for selecting the element in the group - in this case the oldest customer will be chosen for every group:

```
customers.GroupBy(c => c.FirstName + c.LastName).
          Select(g => g.OrderBy(c => c.DateofBirth).FirstOrDefault()).
          OrderBy(c => c.FirstName).
          ThenBy(c => c.LastName);
```

Comment: Third rule is for case if the list have more the one customer having same name. At that time sort by DateofBirth.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier - if you have more than one customer with the same name, they will be grouped into one. But if you don't want to 'merge' them, you don't really need a `GroupBy` - just use `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...).ThenBy(...)`. What kind of output do you expect, btw? If you want a flat list - use `ToList()` on my queries, in case you want, for example, `List<IGrouping<Customer>>` - apply `ToList()` to Mark Heath's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems slightly strange to group on customer name, but this will do it

```
var groups = from c in customers 
                let name = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName
                orderby name ascending, c.DateofBirth ascending
                group c by name into g
                select g;
```

Comment: You don't really need that space between the names, do you?

Comment: @Yakimych well it makes the group.Key look a bit nicer

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortList = (from c in customers
                             group c by new 
                             { 
                                 c.FirstName, 
                                 c.LastName, 
                                 c.DateofBirth 
                             } into g
                             select new Customer()
                             { 
                                 FirstName = g.Key.FirstName, 
                                 LastName = g.Key.LastName, 
                                 DateofBirth = g.Key.DateofBirth 
                             }).OrderBy( x => x.FirstName )
                             .ThenBy( x=> x.LastName)
                             .ThenBy(x=> x.DateofBirth);
```